# Can Crystal Reports Object Expose Data Table

Tags: crystal-reports

Good day.

We're creating crystal reports by providing the report with a data table.

```
  myReport.dataSource = myDataTable
```

Is there a way to get the data table back from the report object later in the code?

```
  DataTable myDataTable = myReport.getDataSource()
```

Thanks
ST

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with following way

```
 DataTable myDataTable = myReport.Database.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that but I don't see any way to iterate the Tables[0] object.  I'm having a hard time finding a API documentation.  The object has a Fields[] object that exactly matches the columns in my original data table.  However, there doesn't seem to be a way to iteate over the rows.  Any thoughts?